# Adding subdivisions without disrupting details

Tags: modeling

It's my first time asking a question here and I hope anyone could help.
I've recently watched a video about modeling a super simple object, starting with very low poly mesh in order to achieve the block out shape and some major details. As the mesh progresses the tutor would increase the number of edges in order to get more geometry for finer details. The software he was using was Maya and what he did seemed like a piece of cake. Since I use Blender I tried the same steps but it didn't work out as expected. If I went for edit mode>subdivide>smoothness=0, the overall mesh would be very lumpy but the detail would come out nice. If I did edit mode>subdivide>smoothness=1, it would be the other way around.
So, my question is: is there a way of adding more geometry without sacrificing any details already made?

Thank you!

Comment: What does it give if you apply a Subdivision Surface modifier instead?

Comment: SubD modifier does work. Problem is that geometry gets too dense too quick. The other drawback is that newly created faces are non workable unless the modifier has been applied.